# ARM Template - create SQL Server firewall rule for Web App

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I have created SQL Server and Database, Web App, published website and database and get to the log on screen of the website.

When I log in I receive a 500 including the IP address of the web app which currently isn't allowed to access the newly created SQL Server.

I'd very much like to harvest the assigned IP address (suspect it is AZURE internal IP address) to create a firewall rule in the template.

I'm successfully doing things like adding app settings for storage account keys and database connections strings. And these are working nicely.

Very frustrating to not be able to find any reference to the internal IP of the web site. I've tried the object explorer in the azure portal.

Suggestions appreciated!
Andy

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Azure SQL, about how to set Azure Database firewall, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure).

> Very frustrating to not be able to find any reference to the internal IP of the web site?

If want to let Azure service to access Azure SQL database, we just need to set

**Allow access to Azure services** on. And default value is **on**.

[image]

We also could get the outbound IPs, we can get them from the azure resources(https://resources.azure.com/) then add the outboundIpAddresses to the Azure SQL firewall rule allowed IP list.

[image]

**Note** : For Azure WebApp, the outboundIpAddresses are not static ips, they may be changed when we restart the WebApp or change WebApp service plan.

If we want to add firewall rule via ARM template, we could use the following demo code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
      "testfirewallAdminLogin": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
      },
      "testfirewallAdminLoginPassword": {
          "type": "securestring"
      }},
  "variables": {
      "testfirewallName": "[concat('testfirewall', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"},
  "resources": [
      {
          "name": "[variables('testfirewallName')]",
          "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
          "dependsOn": [ ],
          "tags": {
              "displayName": "testfirewall"
          },
          "properties": {
              "administratorLogin": "[parameters('testfirewallAdminLogin')]",
              "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('testfirewallAdminLoginPassword')]"
          },
          "resources": [
              {
                  "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
                  "type": "firewallrules",
                  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                  "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
                  "dependsOn": [
                      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('testfirewallName'))]"
                  ],
                "properties": {
                  "startIpAddress": "x.x.x.x",
                  "endIpAddress": "x.x.x.x"
                }
              }
          ]
      }],
  "outputs": {

  }
}
```